# Database Refresh

Tags: database

How often do you refresh your development database from production database?Since there are many types of projects (targeting different domains) I would like to know how it is being done and at what intervals(days/months/years) it is being done ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

While working at Callaway Golf we had an automated build that would completely refresh the database from a baseline.  This baseline would be updated (from production) almost daily.  We had a set up scripts (DTS) that would do this for us.  So if there was some new and interesting information we could easily do it a couple times of day, once a week, etc.  The key here is automation to perform the task.  If it is easy to do then when it is done is really only dependent on how performing the task impacts the load on the production database, the network, and the amount of time it takes to complete it.  This could of course be set up as a schedule task to run at off peak hours and before the dev team gets in in the morning.

Answer (score 2):

The key things in refreshing your development database are:

(1) Automate the refresh through a script.

(2) Obfuscate the data in your development database since you do not want your developers to see the real data or you could do some sampling of your production database.

(3) Decide the frequency of the refresh -- I usually do it once a week.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of work you're doing. If you're debugging issues that are closely related to the data, then frequent updates are good.

If you're doing data Quality Assurance (which often involves writing code to detect and repair it, that you have to develop and test away from the production server), then you need extremely fresh data.  The bad data that is the most valuable to fix is the data that was just inserted or updated today.

If you are writing client code, then infrequent updates are good.  Often when I'm writing C# UI code, I could care less what the data is, I just care if it shows up in the right box on the screen.

If you have data with any security issues, you should stop using production data--i.e. never  update from production--and get a good sample data generator.  Writing a good sample data generator is hard, so 3rd party products are the way to go. MS Data Dude comes to mind, and I recommend Sql RedGate's data generator.

And finally, how hard is it to get a copy of the production data? If it is cheap and automatable, just get a new copy every night.  If it is expensive (requires the attention of a very busy DBA), well, resource constraints might answer the question for you regardless to these other concerns.

Answer (score 0):

We tend to refresh every couple of days, or perhaps once a week or so if things are "normal," though if we're investigating something amiss we may do so more much more often.

Our production database is about 1GB, so it's not a trivial thing to copy around.  Also, for us there's generally no burning need to get current data from production into the dev systems.

The "how" is simply a MySQL "backup" and "restore"

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of cases, refreshing the dev database really isn't that important.  Often production systems have far more data that required for development, and working with such a large dataset can be a hassle for several reasons.  Examples include development on the interface, where it's more important to have *some* data instead of anything specific.  In this case, it's more customary to thin out the production database to a smaller subset of real data.  After you do this once, it's not really that important to update, as long as all schema changes are pushed through the dev database(s).

On the other hand, performance bugs may often require production-sized databases to be able to reproduce and identify bottlenecks, so in this scenario it is extremely useful to have an almost-realtime database.  Many issues may only present themselves with the exact data used in production.

Answer (score 0):

We tend to always go back to an on-demand schedule.  We have many different databases that are used in a suite of applications.  We stay away from automatic DEV databases b/c many of our code changes involve database changes and I don't want anything overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all, the dev databases (one per developer) get setup by a script or similar a couple of times a day, possibly a couple hundred times when running db tests locally. This includes a couple of records for playing around

Of course we still need a database with at least parts of production in it, for integration and scalability tests. We are aiming for a daily automated refresh. But we aren't there yet.